# Java Hibernate : How can I get two objects from same id

Tags: java, hibernate

The issue is that **I want to have two different Company objects for the same company ID**. And I can’t.

```
  Company companyBefore = companyService.findById(id);
  Company companyAfter = companyService.updateCompanyFromDTO(companyDTO);
  em.merge(companyAfter);
  Company companyAfter = companyService.findById(id);
```

**Problem is :** at the end both “before” and “after” will point to the same object with lost “before update” state.

I, even tried it as :

```
  Company companyBefore = companyService.findById(id);
  Company companyAfter = companyService.updateCompanyFromDTO(companyDTO);
```

where, I have the entityManager.merge inside the companyService.updateCompanyFromDTO method. My theory was :

the 2nd time “companyService.findById(id)” is **being returned from cache** and messing up the whole object there again **by auto-save**( hibernate will do whenever it will like to do it ).

However, none of theories seem to be correct.
Any idea, what's going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to detach the `companyBefore` (by calling [`EntityManager::detach`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/entitymanager#detach(java.lang.Object))) before calling `companyService.updateCompanyFromDTO(...)`?

Comment: Yes. tried that too

Comment: I think its working correctly, because both objects point to the same thing stored in your database (thats the whole point of hibernate, isn't it?). If you wanted to keep a record of how it was before, you could create a DTO and initialise it with all the information from `companyBefore`. That way you'll have an object that isn't managed by hibernate and just stores the data/state of exactly what you want :D

Comment: @VictorGram detach should do te trick I think. If not, copy the state yourself